# Resque tasks always fail - uninitialized job constants?

Tags: ruby, heroku, background, sinatra, resque

I've tried using Resque before and was met with unmitigated failure. I'm revisiting it again with the same results...

`resque.rake`:

```
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

`test.rb`:

```
require 'resque'

class FileWorker
  @queue = :save_to_file

  def self.perform(str)
    File.open('./' + Time.now.to_s + '.txt', 'w+') do |f|
      f << "test 123"
    end
  end
end

Resque.enqueue(FileWorker, "12345567".split('').shuffle.join)
```

`Gemfile`:

```
gem 'resque'
gem 'rake'
```

It seems like running `test.rb` on its own successfully queues the job:

[image]

However, running `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'` in the same folder results in a warning,

> WARNING: This way of doing signal handling is now deprecated. Please
>   see http://hone.heroku.com/resque/2012/08/21/resque-signals.html for
>   more info.

As well as the task being added to "failed" queue with the following reason: `"exception":"NameError","error":"uninitialized constant FileWorker"`

How do I get this to work? Seems like something quite obvious but there's tons of tutorials about Resque spanning many years - some painfully out of date and none explaining how to run workers so they don't fail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This SomeWork constant that is missing. Where is it? Seems to me that you are missing to require something when running it with rake (stuff that is included by default when testing perhaps?).

Comment: I can't see `SomeWork` in any of the code you posted - post the real code.

Comment: Whether I require it `SomeWork` or not (in the rakefile), it still seems that it's missing when push comes to shove with resque

Comment: There's so much that can go wrong, I wish I could help directly. Unfortunately my own experience with Resque is limited to a single project I did as a student.
This may not be helpful, but have you checked out the excellent RailsCasts episode on Resque? http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque

Comment: Do you have the `Resque.enqueue` command only in your test.rb file? You need to [also] have it in your controller, or wherever else you want to initiate the worker.
Oh, and the warning is not relevant to the problem... not that it doesn't matter but alleviating the warning won't solve your problem, and ignoring it won't prevent your problem from being solved.

Comment: have you tried to do your call with `TERM_CHILD=1` as env variable?

Comment: Thank you, your question helper me a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you enqueue a task with Resque, what is stored on Redis is just the name of the job class (as a string) along with the arguments (again as strings) in a JSON object.

When a worker then tries to perform the task, it needs to be able to create an instance of the job class. It does this by using `const_get` and `const_missing`. This is where the error you are seeing occurs, since the worker does not have the definition of `FileWorker` available to it.

The error is the same as if you tried to get an unknown constant in `irb`:

```
> Object.const_missing "FileWorker"
NameError: uninitialized constant FileWorker
```

The solution is to make sure the definition of `FileWorker` is available to your workers. The simplest way to do this would be to just require `test.rb` from your `Rakefile` (or `resque.rake`). In your code this would involve adding another task to the queue, so you might want to move the `FileWorker` code to its own file where it can be required by both the rake file and the code enqueuing jobs.

`test.rb`:

```
require 'resque'
require './file_worker'

Resque.enqueue(FileWorker, "12345567".split('').shuffle.join)
```

`Rakefile` (note the `:environment` task only makes sense if you are using Rails and will give errors otherwise):

```
require "resque/tasks"
require "./file_worker"
```

`file_worker.rb`:

```
class FileWorker
  @queue = :save_to_file

  def self.perform(str)
    File.open('./' + Time.now.to_s + '.txt', 'w+') do |f|
      f << "test 123"
    end
  end
end
```

Now the workers will be able to create instances of `FileWorker` to complete the tasks.

---

The way to avoid the warning about signals is given in the [page linked to in the message](http://hone.herokuapp.com/resque/2012/08/21/resque-signals.html). Simply set the environment variable `TERM_CHILD` when calling rake:

```
$ rake resque:work QUEUE='*' TERM_CHILD=1
```